# i cannot install 'angular/cli' package. the npm returns an error:Hostname\IP doesnt match certificate altnames

Tags: angularjs, node.js

**Here is the code
**I'm on an institutional wifi network****

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g angular-cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: registry.npmjs
.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.uonbi.ac.ke"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: From the error message: "If you need help, you may report this error at: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues"

Answer (score 0):

I found out this is actually a network connectivity error.
This is a problem faced when you are behind  a corporate web proxy.
Open an command prompt or terminal session and run the following commands to configure npm to work with your web proxy. 
The commands use proxy.company.com as the address and 8080 as the port.

npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080